# Does Android media player supply session id in the HTTP request headers?

Tags: android, http-live-streaming, android-mediaplayer

I know that iOS AV player supplies a UUID session ID in the HTTP request header X-Playback-Session-Id when requesting content chunks from an HTTP streaming server.

What is the behavior of the Android media player in this case? Does it send its session ID to the server at all? If it does, what HTTP request header does it use for this purpose?

Thanks in advance for any feedback!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Having implemented an in-app HTTP server to stream data into an Android MediaPlayer, I am reasonably certain that the HTTP request does *not* include any session id header. As I remember it, the HTTP request is pretty basic.

The Android component that handles all that is called "libstagefright"... you can fish through the source code to see what it actually does. Here's one version of the relevant source file that isn't too old:
https://github.com/nadlabak/android_frameworks_base/blob/gingerbread/media/libstagefright/NuHTTPDataSource.cpp

Comment: Thanks! Based on what I see in the code, the only header passed beyond the range- and timeout-related is the User-Agent header.

Comment: stumbled upon this. May I ask if your in-app server is available on github or similar? I am evaluating this approach as a proxy for reordering the moov atom in a video while streaming.

Comment: Afraid it's been lost somewhere along the way. I'd recommend using something like http://nanohttpd.com/ now.